# Angular 2 http module load issue

Tags: angular, angular2-services

I'm trying to start to rewrite an Angular1 app into Angular 2 app. 
I start this new project with th help of angular-cli but I'm block to import http service.

I added the following line in my main.ts

```
import { HTTP_PROVIDERS } from '@angular/http';
```

And this one in my service that need to use http

```
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
```

And for there two lines I have the following error:

```
Cannot find module '@angular/http'
```

Have you some Idea about what can i miss ? 
Thank you.

Comment: most probably you are missing import of http file in index.html, also its good practice to import `HTTP_PROVIDERS` at the time of bootstrap your app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need this file in index.html to load those modules :-

```
<script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/http.dev.js"></script>
```

or

```
<script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/http.js"></script>
```

whichever is in your modules

EDIT :-

I think you need to link only the first file if you using beta in dev mode.both files are present though

Comment: I try this but without result. I Check this example https://github.com/johnpapa/angular2-force and nothing like that in index.html. However I have no node_modules/angular2 in my project. There is only this folder: node_modules/@angular

Comment: on checking the config at your link https://github.com/johnpapa/angular2-force/blob/master/package.json 

its using angular 2 rc version.check if http module stated in package,json was installed successfully.

anyways, i suggest you to use more stable beta version. rc is old now.

check this repo :- https://github.com/mschwarzmueller/angular-2-introduction

and this https://github.com/bapatel1/Learning-Angular-2.0

Comment: beta is old, rc is new.  Match your configuration with [angular's quickstart guide](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html)

Comment: I'm ok with A_Singh rc have 4 day. But thank you Sumeet this is a package.json issue !