# Where to put files that a Angular application needs to load with Http?

Tags: angular

I'm using `http` request to load a json file, but I'm not actually sure where the config file needs to live.

```
    this.http.get('env.json')
    .map(res => res.json()).catch((error: any, caught: Observable<any>) => {
        console.log('no');
        return Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error');
    }).subscribe(() => {
        console.log('yes');
    });
```

After running `ng serve`, there is no `dist` folder. I don't think I see a directory where items will get copied from into a `dist` folder.

So where do I put files that my application needs to load with `Http`?

Comment: ng serve will not create dist folder because you are running in dev mode. in order to create dist folder run as production mode by passing --prod [ng build --prod]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `env.json` need to be bundled into `dist` folder and deployed with your other compiled source code, you can simply add it to your project's `assets` folder(*any folder in your project will be ok*) and also add `assets` folder at `.angular-cli.json`'s `assets` array as below:

```
"assets": [
  "assets",     // any folder in your project which contains the config file will be ok
  ...
],
```

And for retrieving data of `env.json` via `http`, just use it's path as

```
this.http.get('assets/env.json')
```

Comment: That's cool. Don't know why I haven't encountered this need before. So do I need to add 'assets/' to the request?

Comment: And is this all the same for the newer HttpClient vs the old Http?

Comment: @BBaysinger yes, see my updated part about how to retrieve the data.

Comment: @BBaysinger they are the same. But be aware that `http` has been deprecated since angular V5.

Comment: In one project it works, just as you say. In another project, it's not. I'm seeing the error being caught, but not even seeing a request in console for the file. Going insane.

Comment: @BBaysinger Sorry, I don't know what's difference between your two project, basically it should always work.

Comment: I duplicated the code into a different place in my app, and it works, but I'm still not seeing the request in the console. Kinda hard to debug that way.

Comment: @BBaysinger the request should be found at `network` tag.

Comment: Yes, I'm looking in the network tab. It doesn't show anything for that file in either Chrome or FF.

Comment: I figured it out. The http calls were being diverted because of InMemoryWebApiModule. I would have figured all this out on my own if it weren't for that. Here's how I figured it out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39085512/angular2-error-collection-not-found