# How to get cors to work properly with angular (apollo client ) and django/graphene

Tags: python, django, angular, apollo-client, graphene-python

I am trying to build an application with `python-graphene` and `django` to persist data on the database side and using angular on the client side.

I have developed both sides and they are working well independently, angular using the `in-memory-web-api` and graphene using `insomnia` (a `postman` style application for linux).

To integrate them, I am trying to use `apollo-angular`. However, the request is returning a 404.

I am fairly new to web development, so I might be missing something trivial.

Searching online I found out that because the server is running on `http://localhost:8000` and the application is running on `http://localhost:4200`, I needed to have `CORS` setup on the server side.

I have followed the instructions on the [manual](https://pypi.org/project/django-cors-headers/):

1. Install `corsheaders` via `pip install django-cors-headers`.
2. Add `corsheaders` to `INSTALLED_APPS`.
3. Add `corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware` topmost at `MIDDLEWARE`.

But still the error persisted.

That is when I came across [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35760943/how-can-i-enable-cors-on-django-rest-framework) and the answers seemed to be relevant. so I:

1. Added `CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True` and `CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True` to `settings.py` at the server.
2. Removed `django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware` from `MIDDLEWERE`.
3. Added the `withCredentials` header to the request at the client side.
4. Cleaned the browser cashed data and cookies.

But still the error persisted.

Here is my component which contains the query:

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Patient } from '../patient';
import gql from 'graphql-tag';
import { Apollo } from 'apollo-angular';

const GET_PATIENTS = gql`
query all_patients {
    patients{
        id
        name
        age
    }
}
`;

export interface GetPatientsResponse {
    patients: Patient[];
    loading: boolean;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-dashboard',
  templateUrl: './dashboard.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dashboard.component.css']
})
export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit {
    patients: Patient[] = [];
    loading = true;

    constructor(private apollo: Apollo) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.apollo.watchQuery<GetPatientsResponse>({
            query: GET_PATIENTS
        }).valueChanges.subscribe((response) => {
            this.patients = response.data.patients;
            this.loading = response.data.loading;
        });
    }
}
```

Also, I have added these to `graphql.module.ts`:

```js
const uri = 'http://localhost:8000/graphql/';

export function createApollo(httpLink: HttpLink) {
  return {
    link: httpLink.create({uri: 'http://localhost:8000/graphql/', withCredentials: true}),
    cache: new InMemoryCache(),
  };
}
```

I expected to receive the `json` from the server with the result from my query and got a `404: http://localhost:8000/graphql/ Not Found` instead.

What am I missing?

Comment: 404 suggests that your django urls may be misconfigured, can you shared them?

Comment: Thanks Iain, what I have in `urls.py`, under `urlpatterns` is `path('admin/', admin.site.urls)` and `path('graphql/', csrf_exempt(GraphQLView.as_view(graphiql=True))) `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching for a long time I finally discovered what was the blunder after reading [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40516208/8250094).

I was using both the `angular-in-memory-web-api` and trying to send the requests to my own server, which was resulting in the error.

By removing the `angular-in-memory-web-api` from my `app.module.ts` everything worked as expected.